# Visual Studio Code show only user snippets in suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code show only my snippets when suggestions come up when typing?
I've tried adding different options to my settings.jason file, including trying to make suggestions come on top of others but still no success. Sometimes my snippets don't come on top, or don't come at all in the suggestions box.

Any ideas on how to make only my snippets show, or at least make sure they always come at the top of the list?

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off"
    },
```

Comment: give the user snippets a special prefix like `xx`

Comment: still not the best solution

Comment: create a pull request for a new setting and the logic to execute it